# sIFR and javascript events

Tags: sifr

I'm having a bit of trouble with sIFR and javascript:

http://veda.onenw.org:8081/yes/yes/ (local instance)

If you look in the top blue feature box where it cycles between the two images, you'll see that the word "featured" picks up sIFR styling, then loses it when the javascript event is triggered.

Is there a way to make sIFR play nicely with Javascript?
Thanks,
- Veda

PS, this is a duplicate from the Joyent forum.

Answer (score 0):

The example is currently down, but I suspect that cycling the images changes the HTML that contains "featured". It sounds like this resets it to a pre-sIFR state, so run the `sIFR.replace()` calls again to re-replace the text.